# ImageView layout_height on different screens - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have `ScrollView` with custom item layout. Each layout have two `ImageView`s. I'm setting the `layout_width` on both images to 0dp, and `layout_weight:1` for images to have half of the screen for every phone/tablet screen. But how can I set the `layout_height`....? If I make if fixed (example 150dp) it is great for phones, but it not for tablets. Any solution for this...?

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear

Comment: In short...How to set android:layout_height on ImageView to look nice on phone(with small height) and on tablet (with big height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello  if you don't want to use different folder in layout their is one way to support multiple screen size you can use     layout_height = wrap_content and fix the image size and I hope this link be helpful to you

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
And the next link will help you sure,
   http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks my friend, the second link is my correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two option:

1. create another layout directory with screen size qualifier for each screen size you care about
2. set the height to fill_parent and that way it will always fill the parent layout.